# How to make UILabel look etched like section header in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UITableView with a view in the header. This view has the pinstripe background and contains a UILabel. I want the UILabel text to look like the text of a section header. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
label.font         = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:label.font.pointSize];
label.textColor    = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
label.shadowColor  = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a variation of the following:

```
label.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: This is close, but still doesn't look like the title of a section header

Comment: You'll just need to tweak and test it. This is the general process for applying a shadow to a label.